# Passing an environment-variable into a php commandline script

Tags: php, environment-variables, command-line-interface

I want to set an environment-variable, then access it in PHP, but cannot find how to do so.

In the (linux) shell, I run:

```
$ APP_ENV="development"
$ export $APP_ENV
```

Then I run a simple test script testenv.php:

```
<?php
print $_ENV["APP_ENV"];
print getenv("APP_ENV");
```

From the same shell where that variable was set:

```
$ php testenv.php
```

This Prints nothing and throws a notice:

```
Notice: Undefined index: APP_ENV in /xxxx/envtest.php on line 2
```

Notice makes sense, because APP_ENV is simply not found in the environment-variables, `getenv()` throws no warning but simply returns nothing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use `$` in the `export` command, it should be:

```
export APP_ENV
```

You can combine this with the assignment:

```
export APP_ENV="development"
```

With the `$`, you were effectively doing:

```
export development
```

Comment: i think OP included the "$" merely to emphasize that those lines are shell commands.

Comment: @cuewizchris I'm not talking about the `$` before `export`, I'm talking about the one _after_ it.

Comment: @cuewizchris actually no Barmar is correct  export $APP_ENV shouldn't have a $ in front

Answer (score 12):

## Problem 1 Exporting environment variables

Your export is incorrect.

```
$ APP_ENV="development"
$ export APP_ENV
```

Notice that the `$` is missing from the export statement! :P

First check getenv to make sure that export works:

```
<?php
  echo getenv ("APP_ENV");
?>
```

## Problem 2: Undefined index on this:

```
<?php
   echo $_ENV["APP_ENV"];
?>
```

If you get a proper value from `getenv` but not the superglobal `$_ENV` then you may have to check your ini file.

Quoting php.org:

> If your $_ENV array is mysteriously empty, but you still see the
>   variables when calling getenv() or in your phpinfo(), check your
>   http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order ini
>   setting to ensure it includes "E" in the string.

Comment: My problem was that `variables_order` did not include E and I don't think I would've found that myself. Great catch!

Comment: If you're only reading that on the next command, you can set and run without exporting as exporting will set the variable available for the whole session:
APP_ENV="development" php testenv.php